# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content. in laravel

Tags: laravel

composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-rc.5
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-rc.5 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[1.0.0-rc.5].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-rc.5 requires illuminate/support ^5.1|^6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.0.6, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.0.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 0):

You package `tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-rc.5` is not compatible with `Laravel7`. To resolve this either you need to use latest package using `composer require tymon/jwt-auth` or you need to use `Laravel6`

References:

https://packagist.org/packages/tymon/jwt-auth#1.0.0-rc.5

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1869

Answer (score 0):

composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop

It still working

composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing lcobucci/jwt (3.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing namshi/jose (7.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing tymon/jwt-auth (dev-develop d4cf9fd): Cloning d4cf9fd2b9 from cache
namshi/jose suggests installing phpseclib/phpseclib (Allows to use Phpseclib as crypto engine, use version ^2.0.)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover --ansi
>   Discovered Package: facade/ignition
>   Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
>   Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
>   Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
>   Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
>   Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
>   Discovered Package: tymon/jwt-auth
>   Package manifest generated successfully.